# Is there a way to write to a Custom app.Config Configuration from code

Tags: c#, list, app-config

So far I have:

```
<section name="PinnedPhotos" type="PhotoViewer.PinnedPhotos, PhotoViewer" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
<PinnedPhotos>
  <add location="Location1.jpg"/>
  <add location="Location2.jpg"/>
</PinnedPhotos>
```

in my app.Config

and in my Code I have:

```
 PinnedPhotos config = (PinnedPhotos)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Sections["PinnedPhotos"];
```

But I would like to update and save `config` from code e.g. Adding more photos to be pinned to the existing list. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

```
var isReadOnly = config.Photos.IsReadOnly();
```

returns False... So I guess there should be a way to write to this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:
I needed to add the two Methods to my Collection:

```
    public void Add(string location)
    {
        PhotoElement pe = new PhotoElement(location);
        BaseAdd(pe);
    }
    public void Remove(string location)
    {
        BaseRemove(location);
    }
```

and then It was just a Case of calling:

```
config.CurrentConfiguration.Save();
```